# MongoDB Atlas not connecting. IP is white listed, user is made, dotenv file created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I'm stumped.

My terminal says I am connected, Postman can Get but cannot Post. 
I have disabled time out on postman.

On Mongo DB Atlas I've white listed my IP, added a user, inserted the password.
I've triple checked my syntax. terminal shows no errors.

One thing is that now MongoDB Atlas asks for a dbname?

```
mongodb+srv://username:<password>@clusterX-1lnr6.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

What do I write there?

Been struggling on this for days. Any ideas on what it could be?

How can I ensure that my firewall is not blocking access?

Comment: used this tutorial, my code is basically identical https://youtu.be/vjf774RKrLc